# Can i print int in binary format?

Tags: c, printf, decimal, bin

Can I print an integer in binary without additional cycles, conditions, and so on? I know that you can print a number in HEX `printf("%x", a)` in decimal `printf("%d", a)` in octal `printf("%o", a)`, but i can't find args for binary. Can you help me?

`12 -> 00001100`

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's simply because there is no such format specifier. You need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Sam, Why would you expect and `int` 12 to print in binary as `00001100` and not `1100`?

Comment: "I know that you can print a number in HEX printf("%x", a) ... in octal printf("%o", a)" is amiss.  Those are for _unsigned_ types, not numbers in general.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no, printf doesn't provide a formater to print a integer in binary.

Second, do not get fooled. Using printf adds additional cycles. Converting an integer to a string (displaying it as decimal, hexadecimal, binary or other) takes some operations. In the case of binary, it's just that you have to do the conversion for printf and provide it the string containing the binary representation.